# If I do not update any information in my update form and click "Save" button,the valu of my database auto increase

Tags: php, yii

I am in the learning stage in php.Please help me with my update  form.Advanced thanks. I have a form to update any user information with a button "Save" and "Reset" button.I update any information the version number increase.But the problem is when i do not update any information and click on "Save" button the version number increases.It should not increase.I am giving my Controller and form code....

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new CvUpload;
    $model2=new CvUpload;

    $UserType=new UserType;
    $CvHistory=new CvHistory;
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(!empty($_POST))
    {

        $id = $_POST['CvUpload']['user_id'];
        $cv_type = $_POST['CvUpload']['cv_type'];
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->condition = "user_id = $id AND is_current='yes' AND cv_type='$cv_type'";
        $CvUploadmodel = CvUpload::model()->find($criteria);    
        if(!empty($CvUploadmodel))
        {
            $CvUploadmodel->is_current='no';
            $CvUploadmodel->status='inactive';
            if($CvUploadmodel->save(false)){
                $model->attributes=$_POST['CvUpload'];
                $model->upload_date = new CDbExpression("NOW()");
                $model->update_date = new CDbExpression("NOW()");   
                $model->version_id = $CvUploadmodel->version_id+1;
                if($model->save(false))
                {
                    $CvHistory->cv_id  = $model->cv_id;
                    $CvHistory->user_id  = $model->user_id;
                    $CvHistory->job_title_id  = $model->job_title_id;
                    $CvHistory->cv_type  = $model->cv_type;
                    $CvHistory->version_id  = $model->version_id;
                    $CvHistory->file_name  = $model->file_name;
                    $CvHistory->upload_date  = $model->upload_date;
                    $CvHistory->update_date  = $model->update_date;
                    $CvHistory->is_current  = $model->is_current;
                    $CvHistory->status  = $model->status;

                    if($CvHistory->save(false))
                    {
                        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->cv_id));
                    }
                }   
            }   
        }
        else
        {   
            $model->attributes=$_POST['CvUpload'];
            $model->upload_date = new CDbExpression("NOW()");
            $model->update_date = new CDbExpression("NOW()");
            $model->version_id=1;

            if($model->save())
            {
                $CvHistory->cv_id  = $model->cv_id;
                $CvHistory->user_id  = $model->user_id;
                $CvHistory->job_title_id  = $model->job_title_id;
                $CvHistory->cv_type  = $model->cv_type;
                $CvHistory->version_id  = $model->version_id;
                $CvHistory->file_name  = $model->file_name;
                $CvHistory->upload_date  = $model->upload_date;
                $CvHistory->update_date  = $model->update_date;
                $CvHistory->is_current  = $model->is_current;
                $CvHistory->status  = $model->status;

                if($CvHistory->save(false))
                {
                    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->cv_id));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'UserType'=>$UserType,
        'CvHistory'=>$CvHistory,
    ));
}
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    $CvHistory=new CvHistory;
    if(isset($_POST['CvUpload']))

    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['CvUpload'];
        if($model->save())
        {
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->condition = "cv_id = $model->cv_id AND is_current = 'yes'";
            $CvHistory = CvHistory::model()->find($criteria);
            $CvHistory->is_current = 'no';
            $CvHistory->status = 'inactive';

        if($CvHistory->save(false))
        {
            $new_CvHistory=new CvHistory;

            $new_CvHistory->cv_id  = $model->cv_id;
            $new_CvHistory->user_id  = $model->user_id;
            $new_CvHistory->job_title_id  = $model->job_title_id;
            $new_CvHistory->cv_type  = $model->cv_type;
            $new_CvHistory->version_id  = $CvHistory->version_id+1;
            $model->version_id = $new_CvHistory->version_id ;
            $new_CvHistory->file_name  = $model->file_name;
            $new_CvHistory->upload_date  = $model->upload_date;
            $new_CvHistory->update_date  = new CDbExpression("NOW()");
            $model->update_date = $new_CvHistory->update_date ;

            $new_CvHistory->status  = $model->status;
            $new_CvHistory->is_current  = "yes";
            $new_CvHistory->save(false);
            $model->save(false);
            if($new_CvHistory->save(false))$this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->cv_id));

        }

        }   
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'CvHistory'=>$CvHistory,

    ));
}
```

MY form button code:

```
  <style>
    #type {
        background-color:#f5f5f5;
        font-family: 'Arial';
        font-size: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
            color:#b2b2b2;
        border:none;
            float: right;
    }

    div.form label {
        display: block;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .types-add{
        float: right;
    }


    #type:hover {
        border: none;    
    }

</style>

<?php if (Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('created')): ?>
        <div class="flash-success">
            <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('created'); ?>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="form">

    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget(
        'booster.widgets.TbActiveForm', 
        array(
            'id'=>'CvUpload-form',
            'type' => 'horizontal',
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'class' => 'well',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        )
        )); 
    ?>
    <fieldset>
  <h1 align="center">CV Upload</h1>
    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>


<div class="row">
    <?php
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
        echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
                $model,
                'user_id',
                array(
                    'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                        'class' => 'col-sm-5',
                    ),
                    'widgetOptions' => array(
                        'data' => CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll($criteria), 'id', 'user_id'),
                        'dataProvider'=>$model->searchByUserId(Yii::app()->user->getId()),
                        'htmlOptions' => array('prompt'=>'Select'),
                    )

                )
            ); ?>
    </div>




        <div class="row" id="jobTitle">
        <?php 
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->condition = "status= 'active'";
            echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
                $model,
                'job_title_id',
                array(
                    'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                        'class' => 'col-sm-5',
                    ),
                    'widgetOptions' => array(
                        'data' => CHtml::listData(JobTitle::model()->findAll($criteria), 'id', 'name'),
                        'htmlOptions' => array('prompt'=>'Select job title'),
                    )

                )
            ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php  echo CHtml::form($this->createUrl('uploadreport'), 'post', array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));?>
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label required" for="CvUpload_file_name">
        Upload File
    </label>
    <div class="row" id="file_upload" style="margin-left:20%; margin-bottom:2%;">
         <?php
            $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload',array(
                'name'        => 'files',
                'accept'      => 'doc|docx|pdf',
                'max'         => 1,
                'htmlOptions' => array('size' => 25),
            ));             
            echo CHtml::htmlButton('Upload',array(
            'onclick'=>'javascript: send();', // on submit call JS send() function
            'id'=> 'post-submit-btn', // button id 'newcreate'
            'class'=>'btn btn-primary',
        ));
        ?>

    </div>

        <?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript("jquery"); ?>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.0.js"></script>

            <script>
                function send(){
                    var formData = new FormData($("#CvUpload-form")[0]);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("CvUpload/upload"); ?>',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        datatype:'json',

                        beforeSend: function() {

                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                           $("#CvUpload_file_name").val(data);
                        },

                        complete: function() {

                        },

                        error: function (data) {
                            alert("There may a error on uploading. Try again later");
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    });

                    return false;
                }
            </script>       
    <div class="row" id="file_name">
        <?php echo $form->textFieldGroup(
        $model,'file_name',
           array(
             'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
               'class'=> 'col-sm-5',
             ),
           )
            );
        ?>
    </div>  

            <div class="row" id="statustype">
        <?php 
            $status = array('active'=>'Active', 'inactive'=>'Inactive');
            echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
                $model,
                'status',
                array(
                    'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                        'class' => 'col-sm-5',
                    ),
                    'widgetOptions' => array(
                        'data' => $status,
                        'htmlOptions' => array('prompt'=>'Select a status'),
                    )

                )
            ); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="statustype">

    <?php 
            $is_current = array('yes'=>'Yes', 'no'=>'No');
            echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
                $model,
                'is_current',
                array(
                    'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                        'class' => 'col-sm-5',
                    ),
                    'widgetOptions' => array(
                        'data' => $is_current,
                        'htmlOptions' => array('prompt'=>'Select a status'),
                    )

                )
            ); ?>       
    </div>
 <div class="row buttons">
         <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save',array(
         'class'=>'btn btn-primary',
         'style'=>"position:relative; margin-left:25%",
         'id'=> 'yt1', // button id
         )); ?>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->














<!--/*/*
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'cv-upload-form',

    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'user_id',array('size'=>20,'maxlength'=>20)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'user_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'upload_date');enter code here ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'upload_date'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'upload_date'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'file_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'file_name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>150)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'file_name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'file_location'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'file_location',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>150)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'file_location'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't change form values, it doesn't mean that this data wouldn't be sended to server.

Here at least button save will sended, so this case will always true:

```
if(!empty($_POST))
```

You didn't show whole form, but I suggest that fields user_id and cv_type has values (no mater values where changed or not, if form has fields they will be submited)

```
$id = $_POST['CvUpload']['user_id'];
$cv_type = $_POST['CvUpload']['cv_type'];
```

That's why model `$CvUploadmodel = CvUpload::model()->find($criteria);` loads and increament `version_id`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Can you say more about the issue fixing.I did not get the point.Here i am giving you the Controller and form code.

My Controller:

Comment: I didn't get the point can say more clearly please.thanks... @SiZE

Comment: May be you need to remove string `$new_CvHistory->version_id  = $CvHistory->version_id+1;` under saving history section `if($CvHistory->save(false))`?

Comment: hi  again.I remove the string.It is working fine in the update form,the version number is not increasing.But if i update any field in the form the version number should increase.but is not happening after removing the string line you suggested. Can you help me with this one...Thanks in advanced ... @SiZE

Comment: You need check if fields changed or not. 1. You may add hidden field flag and change it with JS change events for each field. 2. Before set model attributes, load model data to compare each field with POST data.

Comment: Can you give me an example.I not good at JS and how to compare the fields,loading models regarding the code i given .It may seems a silly question but i will be much more helpful.....Thanks @ SiZE

Comment: `$is_changed = false; if ( $model->job_title_id != $_POST['CvUpload']['job_title_id'] ) { $is_changed = true; }` and so on

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.Can you be more specific on the part you said 1. You may add hidden field flag and change it with JS change events for each field. code example will be much more helpful as you given before in the last comments....... @SiZE

Comment: `$('#<?=CHtml::activeId($model,'job_title_id')?>').on('change',function(){ $('#fields_changed').val('1'); });`

Comment: create `<?=CHtml::hiddenField('fields_changed','0',array('id'=>'fields_changed'))?>`

Comment: `If ( $_POST['fields_changed'] == 1 ) /* then increment counter*/`

Comment: i failed to do it.Can you please help me out, how to solve it by code @SiZE

Comment: I am having problem in my controller and in my form code as i have given ...can you help me out with code.may be i am not doing it right.i am still at learning stage... thanks.. @SiZE